# Algorithm needed for solving building-blocks problem

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

Consider the following scenario:

1. We have a number of sequential building blocks (e.g. **12 building blocks**, ordered from 1 to 12), distributed randomly (but not necessarily equally) on a number of builders (e.g. **3 builders**).
2. The builders are required to **work in order and start building the wall from block number 4**, both ways; down to block number 1 or up to block 12.
3. Each builder **doesn't have any knowledge about what block numbers the other builders may have, though he knows how many.**
4. Builders must try to finish first by preventing others from making their moves. **They should not pass and have to place a block, if they can.**
   Any builder who finishes all his blocks first will be granted the highest reward, then the second, and so on...

Can we predict who will finish first, second and last? Is there any algorithm the builders should follow to get their work done first?

The following is a practical example of the problem:
Let us say:

```
builder 1 has: b2 b5 b8 b9
builder 2 has: b1 b11
builder 3 has: b3 b4 b6 b7 b10 b12
```

builder 1, and builder 2 will have to wait for builder 3 to place b4.
builder 3 will place b4, and gives his place back to builder 1.

```
wall: b4
```

builder 1 will have to put up b5, as there are no other options for him.

```
wall: b4 b5
```

builder 2 will follow, but he cant place his blocks, he will have to wait for b2 or b10.
builder 3 now have two options: b3 or b6, he must choose the one which help him finish first.

```
wall: b4 b5 b6
```

builder 1 has nothing to do, he'll pass his turn to builder 2.
builder 2 is still waiting for the installation of b2 or b10.
builder 3 will have to place b7.

```
wall: b4 b5 b6 b7
```

builder 1 now will place b8.

```
wall: b4 b5 b6 b7 b8
```

builder 2 is still waiting patiently...
builder 3 is forced to put down b3, as there are no other options, he was hoping that builder 2 may place b9... but his hope faded!

```
wall: b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8
```

builder 1 is totally in charge now, and feeling very happy! but he is confused! after thinking he decided that b2 may allow him to keep preventing a larger number of blocks, which in turn increases his chance.

```
wall: b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8
```

builder 2 says: finally! some action! and places b1.

```
wall: b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8
```

builder 3 lost his hope on becoming first!
builder 1 now will install his final block and go home with the biggest reward!

```
wall: b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9
```

builder 2 will wait...
builder 3 sadly places b10
builder 2 places b11 and goes home with the second reward...

Any known algorithm for solving such problems?

Comment: Since this sounds like a homework problem, I'm going to guess that there is a known algorithm.  What it is specifically, is probably up to you.

Comment: Note that in the example you give, both b2 and b9 are valid choices - essentially, 2nd and 3rd are down to chance.

Comment: @Anon Even if Builder 1 plays b9 first, Builder 3 still comes in 3rd. Play it out: Builder 1 plays b9; Builder 2 can't play; Builder 3 plays b10; Builder 1 plays b2 and wins; Builder 2 plays b1; Builder 3 is stuck; Builder 2 plays b11 and gets 2nd place.

Comment: Some precisions on the rules: 1/ Do you HAVE to play if you can, or do you have the possibility to pass (if everyone passes... oh well) ? 2/ Might be interesting to consider starting from another block, is it possible ?

Comment: This is not a homework problem though I wrote it to sound that way... perhaps because I used to teach... I'm working on a process management program which distributes random-sized parts of sequential data (building blocks), the code should predict at the beginning the sequence of finished processes. The time taken for building each block by any process is equal.

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, a player's strength is a function of the range spanned by his highest and lowest blocks. In your example game, we can see that Builder 1 completely dominates Builder 2.

```
Builder 1:            2 ----------- 9   
Builder 2:          1 ----------------- 11
Builder 3:              3 --------------- 12

Start position:           ^^
```

Since the game starts on b4, the most important pieces are at the high end. For example, Builder 3 has b3, which prevents 2 other moves (b2 and b1); however, this isn't very decisive. Block b3, in its ability to prevent b2 and b1, is only as powerful as b5, which prevents b6 and b7.

**The real power lies on the right side of the diagram above**. This means that games with the initial starting ranges depicted above will usually finish like this: Builder 1, Builder 2, and then Builder 3.

As for player strategy, here's an admittedly speculative guideline: hold on to your most powerful pieces, meaning those that prevent the largest number of moves by other players. In this strategy, every piece you hold can be assigned a score based on the number of other moves it prevents.

For example, suppose the wall is at b3-b4-b5 and that you hold b2, b6, and b9. You can play either b2 or b6. How do you value your pieces?

```
b2 score = 1 (prevents b1)
b9 score = 3 (prevents b10, b11, b12)
b6 score = 2 (prevents b7, b8)
```

Note that b6 does not get credit for preventing b10 and higher, because b9 is doing that job (Matthieu M. also makes this point). In this scenario, you should prefer to play b2 first because it exposes you to the least risk of another player finishing.

Other answers have raised interesting ideas about not wanting to prevent your own progress, suggesting that you should play b6 first. But I don't think there is anything to be gained by accelerating the movement toward b9. You want to delay b9 as long as possible, because it's the piece that gives you the most insurance (from a probabilistic point of view) of preventing other players from finishing.

**Update:**

I wrote a Perl simulation to test a few simple player strategies. I'm starting to wonder whether player strategy is irrelevant. I tried the following: (a) pick the highest block; (b) pick the lowest block; and (c) my recommended strategy of picking the safest block (the one that prevents the most moves by others). I evaluated the strategies by awarding 3 points for 1st place, 2 for 2nd, and 1 for 3rd. None of these strategies performed consistently better (or worse) than random selection.

Certainly, one can concoct scenarios where a player's choice affects the outcome. For example, if the blocks are distributed like this, player 3 will get either 1st or 2nd place.

```
b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6  b7  b8  b9  b10  b11  b12
2   1   3   1   3   2   2   2   2   2    2    2
```

However, from a probabilistic point of view, this variation in outcome can be simplified to the following: player 3 will win unless he picks a the block adjacent to a player who has only one block remaining. In other words, the precise outcome is a coin toss.

So here's the question: **Can anyone provide a scenario with an outcome that is neither foreordained nor a coin toss?** I tried for about 15 minutes and then got bored.

Comment: The range approach seems quite interesting. It's true that the builder with the last block (`1` or `12`) is not really favored and will have to counter by preventing moves on the other end.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-suited variant of the card game [Sevens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sevens_(card_game)) - it also goes by other names; I have heard it widely called Fan Tan.

You might like to search the web for algorithms for that.

<strike>p.s. This smells like a homework assignment. It is considered polite to use the "homework" tag in such circumstances.</strike>

Comment: You are right, I've found that such problems belong to the "Shedding-Type game" category.

p.s. It's not a homework assignment. If it was, I would have used the homework tag. Thanks for your note anyway.

Answer (score 1):

@FM is right - the more pieces you block of your enemies, the better the move is. However, there is another part to the strategy that is not being considered there.

Consider if you have B3, B7, and B11. Suppose that B3 and B7 are currently both legal moves. (You are in a reasonably good position. Because you have neither B12 or B1, you cannot come third.)

Choosing B3 means that you are only opening up B1 and B2, so it is the best move under FM's strategy.

However, by not placing B7, you are delaying the eventual play of B10, which is necessary for you to win. B7 is probably a better move.

Comment: Not sure my answer really adds up to a coherent strategy. However, if it does, I think it emphasizes the importance of end pieces. In that case, the 2 critical pieces in your example are b3 and b11; b7 is irrelevant if we take my idea to its logical (probably absurd) extreme. Which piece prevents more opponent moves: b3 or b11? The former, so protect it. Play b7, exactly as you suggest. It's late. I'm probably overlooking something. :)

Comment: You make a good point. I need to come up with a better example.
If you have B3, B5 and B8. B3 and B5 are playable. Which do you choose: B3 or B5? I think your strategy is B3, and mine is B5.

Comment: Based on "only consider highest and lowest", B8 protects B9-B12 (4 blocks), B3 protects B1, B2 (2 blocks), B5 doesn't protect anything (as you have B8 for that), so play B5.

Comment: Drats; I still haven't proven my point. How about this? You have B2, B3, B5 and B9. B3 and B5 are playable. Again, I would always go B5 even though B3 and B5 appear to be equivalent. More fully, I would always play in the order B5, B3, B2, B9. It gives a better chance of B9 being playable without passing compared to B3, B5, B2, B9.

Comment: What's wrong with passing ? I don't mind passing if I only have one piece and the others are struggling to place theirs.

Comment: @Oddthinking In your most recent scenario, I think it's a mistake to worry about opening up the path toward B9. Ideally, B9 will be your last play of the game. There's no need to rush it. Happily play B3 and even B2, accepting the risk of B1 (it's only one piece). Your strength lies in B5 and B9, because they provide the greatest insurance that the game will end on your terms. I added some more comments to my answer along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have had the precisions yet, let's start with the (reasonable) assumption that if you can play then you have to. It's nice to prevent the game to be stuck.

Because of the rules, you have 0, 1 or 2 moves possible. You can only choose when you are in a `2` moves solution.

**1. Decision Tree**

Like many games, the easiest way to see what happens is to trace a tree of all possible moves and then explore this tree to make your decision. Since there is not much decision taking place, the tree should not be that big.

For example, consider that we are in the state:

```
wall = [3, ..., 8]
b1 = [2,9]
b2 = [1,11]
b3 = [10,12]
```

And it's `b1` turns to play.

```
b1[2] -> b2[1] -> b3[] -> b1[9] (1st) -> b3[10] -> b2[11] (2nd) -> b3[12]
 or
b1[9] -> b2[] -> b3[10] -> b1[2] (1st) -> b2[1] -> b3[] -> b2[11] (2nd) -> b3[12]
                                           or
                                          b2[11] -> b3[12] (2nd) -> b2[1]
```

So basically we have 2 choices in the part of the tree.

1. `b1` gets to choose between `2` and `9`
2. `b2` gets to choose between `1` and `11`

We can summarize the consequences of a choice by listing the positions the players will get, obviously in an unbiased party each player choose in order to get the best position.

So, let's express a reduced version of the tree (where we only show the choices):

```
b1[2] -> [1,2,3]
b1[9] -> b2[1] -> [1,2,3]
b1[9] -> b2[11] -> [1,3,2]
```

Now we can apply a reduced view, based on a given player.

For `b1`, the tree looks like:

```
[2,9] -> [1,1] (both are equivalent)
```

For `b2`, it looks like:

```
[1,11] -> [2,3]
```

For `b3`, there is never a choice...

**2. Possible outcomes**

Of course, the players don't get this tree, since they don't know what the others have, but it gives you, as an observer, the possibility to study the various possible outcomes, at different stages of the party.

Note for example that on this subtree, we have 2 choices, the second being conditional on the first. If we have `Pi(x in {x,y})` express the probability that player `i` choose `x` when facing a choice between `x` and `y`, then we can express the probabilities of each outcome.

```
P([1,2,3]) = P1(2 in {2,9}) + P1(9 in {2,9}) * P2(1 in {1,11})
P([1,3,2]) =                  P1(9 in {2,9}) * P2(11 in {1,11})
```

**3. Players Strategy**

From what we can see here, it appears that the best strategy is to try and block as many pieces as possible: ie when choosing between `1` and `11`, you'd better play `1` because it does not block anyone while `11` blocks 1 piece. However this only works when you are down to 2 pieces.

We need something a bit more generic for the case when you actually have a list of pieces.

For example, if you hold `{3, 9, 11}` and the wall is `[4, ..., 8]` which should you pose ? Apparently `3` blocks less pieces than `9`, but `9` blocks one of your own pieces!

Personally, I would go for `9` in this case, because I will need to place my `11` anyway and `11` blocks less pieces than `3` (with `3` I have a chance of terminating first, with `11` it's less likely...).

I think I can give a score to each piece in my hand, depending on the number of pieces they block:

```
3 -> 2
9 -> 1
11 -> 1
```

While is `9` attributed only `1` ? Because it only blocks `10` since I hold the `11` :)

Then I would play first the piece of the lowest score (if I have a choice).

Comment: It is Obvious that "if you can play then you have to". Good analysis on the subject though... We may need to simplify the problem by stripping down the number of players to two. I was thinking of FM's range approach and I believe it needs more generalization. Range is a simple form of the probability density function of a continuous distribution. In our case the distribution is linear, isn't it? I still need to figure out how to apply that to our case.

Comment: Unfortunately 2 will indeed simplify the problem too much: it drops the "you don't know who have what" issue since what you don't see, the other have :) So we're bound to 3 as a minimal if you wish to maintain the mystery that prevents one from using the Decision Tree.

Comment: True, but 2 players, may help us more in defining an evaluation function. right?

Comment: They may... I must admit I am always wary of changes when they impact the behavior... of course one can always pretend not to guess the bricks of the other player :)